# Tool to analyze page loads

Tags: optimization, page-speed

I have this CI app that shows an interminable loading process. I want to know what chunk of the page is causing this.

Now I am using Firebug with Google PageSpeed and YSlow. Is there something more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Chrome, the "Network" tab from "Developer Tools" can provide details on how long each of the page's resource took to load.

Comment: +1! And more info about Google Chrome's Developer Tools at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/

Comment: For more details, you might also want to check out the [Chrome Speed Tracer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) -- it gives you pretty precise timing information, not only on when which embedded piece of content downloads, but also how & when JavaScript is executed, when your layout needs to be recalculated, etc.

Comment: Nice tool. But its only in FF that occur this. It is the icon over the tab that shows when the request is being sended and when the resources are being downloaded. This icon never stop. Using this tool and Net of firebug all resources shows a properly time and statuses 304 and 200.

Answer (score 0):

The [net panel](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) in Firebug will show you how long each individual resource in a page takes to load.

Comment: Yes, but not helps in this case, THX

Comment: Then you need to expand your question with why it's not helpful, because this is pretty much exactly what you're asking for, as is the Chrome tool mentioned above.

Comment: I already said in my question that I use firebug. I added a comment in the previous answer.